# How to find time complexity of an algorithm when given number of iterations and total time?

Tags: performance, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I understand how to find the time complexity of an algorithm when I've been presented with an algorithm, but I can't seem to get my head around how to work it out when I've been given the number of times the algorithm is executed, and the time taken.

I can sometimes get it, when it's obvious things like O(n), O(n) or O(n^2) but take this question for example:

An algorithm runs a given input of size n.
If n is 4096 the run time is 512 milliseconds.
If n is 16384 the run time is 1024 milliseconds.
If n is 36864 the run time is 1536 milliseconds.

What is the time complexity?

I see that as n * 2, t * 1.5, but I'm not quite sure how to work it out.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This is impossible to answer in general. Your professor probably wants you to fit one of the common time complexities to the values given, but the algorithm might be O(1) for all you know.

Comment: Moreover - some algorithms have different cases. An example is SAT Solvers, which are usually pretty fast, but in their worst cases decay to exponential running time (which is terrible for large values of `n`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you need more than just three datapoints for this kind of question, because of complexities in the system rather than just the algorithm.

What I would do is compare the iterations and the elapsed time and see if you can find a pattern that matches one of the standard time complexities:

- Constant: O(c) where c is a constant.
- Linear: O(n)
- Polynomial: O(n^c) where c is a constant (or even something complicated like O(n^2 + n^6))
- Exponential: O(c^n) where c is a constant.
- Logarithmic: O(log|n|)
- Whatever this is called: O(n log|n| )

Let's go through your problem:

```
n     | time
4096  | 512 ms
16384 | 1024 ms
36864 | 1536 ms
```

When n goes up by a factor of 4 (from 4096 to 16384), the time goes up by a factor of 2 (from 512 to 1024 ms).

When n goes up by a factor of 9 (from 4096 to 36864), the time goes up by a factor of 3 (from 512 to 1536 ms).

A function that matches this is f(n) = n^(1/2). When n goes up by a factor of 4, f(n) goes up by a factor of sqrt(4), etc...

So this is of order O(n^.5), which is polynomial

TLDR: Graph it out and match it to a common function for time-complexity. In the real-world you would probably need more than three datapoints.

edit: I'd like to add that that this should really be more complex. There is likely a constant term in every kind of time complexity. I.e. O(n^c) is more likely O(n^c + K) where K is a constant. We ignore the constant for simplicity when writing this out, but it would show up in your graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure of the actual algorithm, then you would create a line graph, `n` would be on the bottom of the graph, and `y` would be the time it took that number to execute.

If the slope of the line is 0, then it's O(1), if it's linear, then it's O(n), if it's curved, then it's either O(n^2), O(log n), or some other non-linear time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If the time complexity of an algorithm is `n^x`, then the quotient `t_2 / t_1` for the times for inputs `n_1` and `n_2` is

```
(t_2 / t_1) = (n_2 / n_1)^x
```

and if you take logarithms, you get

```
log (t_2 / t_1) = x * log (n_2 / n_1)
```

and can solve for `x`:

```
x = log (t_2 / t_1) / log (n_2 / n_1)
```

In your examples, with `n_1 = 4096` and `t_1 = 512ms`, you get the quotients

```
16384 / 4096 = 4        36864 / 4096 = 9
 1024 / 512  = 2         1536 / 512  = 3
```

so `x = 1/2`.

If the complexity doesn't follow a pure power law, you can estimate the power by evaluating a sufficiently large number of such quotients. If the complexity is actually exponential (or super-exponential), the quotients will grow linearly or super-linearly. The rate of growth can then be used to find the base for the exponential in the exponential case.